# 3 input field form in css and htmt text/javascript

Tags: html, css, forms, input

Hey i was wondering if anyone could tell my why my ftp input field and username are overlapping each other ^.^ i cant suss it out. i have give to ftp host input field an id to try and separate it from the username input field. I would appreciate any help i can get thankyou guys

sorry here what it looks like http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/9287/koyn.png

below is my my style.ss and below that is my .html

```
        body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-1.jpg);
    background-color: #363636;
}

.logo {   top: -90px;
  position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
}

#box {
    background: url(../images/box.png);
    width: 504px;
    height: 383px;
    margin: 15% auto 0;
    position: relative;
}

a.forgot {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 504px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

a.forgot:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

h1 {
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 504px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#box form input[id='ftp'][type=text], #box form input[type=text], #box form input[type=password] {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    background: url(../images/input.png);
    display: block;
    height: 162px;
    width: 339px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.28);
    }

#box form input[id='ftp'][type=text]:focus , #box form input[type=text]:focus, #box form input[type=password]:focus {
    outline: none;
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 -54px;
}

#box form input[id='ftp'][type=text]{
    left: 82px;
    top: 120px;
}

#box form input[type=text]{
    left: 82px;
    top: 60px;
}

#box form input[type=password]{
    left: 82px;
    top: 180px;
}

#box form input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 268px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#box form label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 269px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
}

#box form label:hover {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#box form input[type=button], #box form input[type=submit] {
    background: url(../images/button.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 255px;
    left: 84px;
    width: 203px;
    height: 44px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
}

#box form input[type=button]:hover, #box form input[type=submit]:hover{
    background-position: 0 -44px;
}

#box form input[type=button]:active, #box form input[type=submit]:active{
    background-position: 0 -88px;
}


    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexi-background.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />


</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/flexi-background.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <div id="box">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="yourlogo" />
        <form>
            <input type="text" id='ftp/' onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'ftp':this.value;" value="ftp://" />
            <input type="text" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Username':this.value;" value="Username" />
            <input type="password" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Password':this.value;" value="Password">
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember" value="Remember" />
            <div class="hover-opacity"><label for="remember">store details</label></div>
            <input type="button" name="" value="Log In" />
        </a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should upload your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can play with it. Anyhow, `logo { top: -90px ` is probably what's making your logo cut. Also you need to make the entire box higher. I'll help you with the other things when you upload your code

Comment: Hey thank you for your fast reply, the logo is not troubling me. I cant upload to that site as im using 2 diffrent.css http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/8711/n99u.png

Comment: Well it's very difficult to help without the HTML... From here it looks like you overuse the `absolute position` and that's probably what making the inputs to overlap. Try this guide for proper positioning [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSS styling block that overrides another one:

```
#box form input[id='ftp'][type=text]{
    left: 82px;
    top: 120px;
}

#box form input[type=text]{
    left: 82px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

The second one applies to the ftp input as well.

Should look like this:

```
#box form input[type='text'] {
    left: 82px;
    top: 60px;
}
#box form #ftp {
    top: 120px;
}
```

---

And again I feel obligated to recommend you to learn about **css positioning**, so you won't overuse *position: absolute* so much.

For further reading:

- [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training)/css/positioning/
- [Box Model & Positioning](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/box-model)

Comment: Hi guys i found an easy way to solve my problem and am posting to help anybody that has this problem in the future

i simply changed the input from 'text' to 'url'

#box form input[type=url]{
    left: 82px;
    top: 70px;

thanks for trying to solve my problem tho itay

Comment: That's almost exactly the same as my answer.. Glad that you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

you're facing this problem because you've used absolute positioning for almost every form element. And if you look closely , you actually set the top value for both the ftp and the username form element to identical values. That's why they're overlapping. Setting it to relative will solve your problem.

You should definitely avoid this way of positioning elements mostly because you'll end up with a headache. but if You still have to use  absolute positioning, just make sure your not putting identical values.

```
#box form input[id="ftp"][type="text"], #box form input[type="text"], #box form 
input[type="password"] {
position: absolute;// Set this to relative
....
....
}
```